# html + css + jquery: Toggle Show More/Less Text

Tags: jquery, toggle, show

I'm working on a personal project and I'm having a small issue:

This is my code code and currently works: http://jsfiddle.net/gvM3b/:

```
$(".show-more").click(function () {
    $(this).text("(Show Less)");
$(".text").toggleClass("show-more-height");
});​
```

The issue is that the "(Show More)" text changes to "(Show Less)" but not switches back when needed.

^That's one thing, an additional thing would be if you know how to add the [...] when it says show more but on the text. Been trying to figure it out but had to ask for a little of help, I'm new to jquery.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Update your jQuery:

```
$(".show-more").click(function () {
    if($(".text").hasClass("show-more-height")) {
        $(this).text("(Show Less)");
    } else {
        $(this).text("(Show More)");
    }

    $(".text").toggleClass("show-more-height");
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/gvM3b/1/

Answer (score 4):

Use the ternary operator, for example:

```
$(".show-more").click(function () {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.text($this.text() == "(Show Less)" ? "(Show More)" : "(Show Less)");
  $(".text").toggleClass("show-more-height");
});​
```

Or using [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text2) with a function:

```
$(".show-more").click(function () {
  $(this).text(function (i, oldText) {            
    return oldText == "(Show Less)" ? "(Show More)" : "(Show Less)";      
  });
  $(".text").toggleClass("show-more-height");
});​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hn4Aq/)**.

Comment: This depends too much on the exact text shown, if it was a translatable label your code would not be adequate I think. Works in this particular case of course.

Comment: @JeroenMoons: Indeed, but if it's a translatable label, you could just replace the text with something like `LabelHelper.getLabel("showMore")`. For a given language, the text will not vary.

Comment: Yes you're right. I usually try to avoid checking on that kind of label text, I prefer something less pone to change like a css class. But it's splitting hairs in this situation maybe :)

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
$(".show-more").click(function () {        
    $(".text").toggleClass("show-more-height");
    if(!$(".text").hasClass("show-more-height")){
        $(this).text("Show Less");
    }else{
        $(this).text("Show More");
    }
});
```

​
[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gvM3b/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's one more solution:

```
var i = 0;   

$(".show-more").on('click', function() {
    $(this).text( ++i % 2 ? "(Show Less)" : "(Show More)" );
    $('.text').toggleClass("show-more-height");
});
```

The fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gvM3b/6/

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to recommend the [Jquery more less library](http://shakenandstirredweb.com/playground/jquery-more-less-text/) which takes care of the 'Show More' 'Show Less' problem.

An alternative: [cmtextconstrain](http://coxmediagroup.github.io/jquery-textconstrain/)