# How to set "see more" option on large descriptions in Django?

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates, word-wrap

i am working in django platform using python language. i am showing results in my template file in which i have large description to display. All i want to know is How can we set "see more" option on large Descriptions if text exceeded from 4 lines. and after 4 lines there will be "see more" option appears. just like Facebook long status. and on clicking "see more" option i want to show my whole description. i am new to django help will be appreciated.

here is my code

```
<span class="results-cell-heading">{% trans "Description:" %}</span> 
<span class="results-cell">{% autoescape off %}{{ obj.description }}
{% endautoescape %}</span>
```

here `{{obj.description}}` is the description text.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12240030/html-css-jquery-toggle-show-more-less-text

Comment: it did solve the problem but cause another problem. like if their is no data regarding that field then still see more option is showing

Answer (score 1):

you can adapt the existing templatetags truncatewords to make your owns templatetags:

```
def truncatereadmore(value, arg):
    """
    Truncates a string after a certain number of words.

    Argument: Number of words to truncate after.

    Newlines within the string are removed.
    """
    try:
        length = int(arg[0])
    except ValueError: # Invalid literal for int().
        return value # Fail silently.
    return Truncator(value).words(length, truncate=arg[1])
```

and in the template :

```
{{ value|truncatereadmore:80:"read more" }}
```

I did test it but it's the general idea ;)

Once this is done you'll need a peace of javascript to deal with the "facebook's behavior" you want to see

Comment: cant use this answer's solution. as i am already calling some function

Comment: if i'm not wrong you can use several templatetags {{ value|tag1:parm1:parm2|tag2:parm1:parm2|tag3:parm1:parm2 }}